# Script for dividing files into subfolders, based on the number of files

Tags: powershell

I have a script in powershell that executes the count of all the files and soon after creates a subfolder stops every 100 files, that's for sure however when I have for example: 350 files, 3 folders are created with 100 files and the other 50 are left out , someone can help me, the script follows:

```
$path = "c:\FILES";
$filecount = (Get-ChildItem $path).Count
$maxfilecount = 100;
#endregion variables

#region functions

# Define Write-DateTime function to alias
function Write-DateTime {
    return (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss");
}

# Set alias for quick reference
Set-Alias -Name wdt -Value "Write-DateTime";

#endregion functions

#region Script Body

# Output status to host.
Write-Output "$(wdt): Gathering file names.";

# Get file count
$filecount = (Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -ne $true}).Count;

# Output status to host.
Write-Output "$(wdt): Processing files.";

# Enumerate folders based on filecount and maxfilecount parameter
for($i = 1; $i -le ($filecount/$maxfilecount); $i++) {

    # Clear the $files objects.
    $files = $null;

    # Set the foldername to zero-filled by joining the $path and counter ($i)
    $foldername = Join-Path -Path ($path) -ChildPath ("Disc-{0:0}" -f $i);

    # Output status to host.
    Write-Output "$(wdt): Creating folder $foldername.";

    # Create new folder based on loop counter
    New-Item -Path $foldername -ItemType Directory | Out-Null;

    # Output status to host. 
    Write-Output "$(wdt): Gathering files for $foldername.";

    # Break files into smaller collections to move to subfolders.
    $files = Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -ne $true} | select -first $maxfilecount;

    # Output status to host.
    Write-Output "$(wdt): Moving files to $foldername.";

    # Enumerate collection.
    foreach($file in $files) {
        # Output status to host.
        Write-Output "$(wdt): Moving $($file.fullname).";

        # Move files in collection to subfolder.
        Move-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $foldername;
    }
}
```

Comment: Question should not be tagged as `bash`, only `powershell`.

Comment: Ok, i'am sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Here the `for` loop condition lets you one too short:

```
for($i = 1; $i -le ($filecount/$maxfilecount); $i++) {
```

For instance `4 -le 350/100` returns `False`, so you'll only get three folders. You could initialize the `$i`to `0`, but that would affect the folder names, so simpy increase the end condition by one:

```
for($i = 1; $i -le ($filecount/$maxfilecount + 1); $i++) {
```